# Nextjs and Socket IO

Tags: socket.io, next.js

hope you have a great day! i'm in the middle of learning Socket.IO, of course with the tutorial avail on internet, but i got an obstacle in my journey, in the tutorial seems like everything OK, but when i try, i didn't know why this happend, so basicly i want to make room, then everytime someone join to the room, i got the respond (in the server), `i got the respond` but why i got multiple respond? when inside the room just myself..

here's my code in `server/index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const socketio = require("socket.io")
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const router = require("./router");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

app.use(cors());
app.use(router);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New connection establish!");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User left the room!");
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`));
```

here's my package json on `server`

```
{
  "name": "myserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "myname",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

and here's my `front end`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
let socket;

export default function index({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  const ENDPOINT = "localhost:5000";
  useEffect(() => {
    setRoom(data.room);
    setName(data.name);
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    console.log(socket);
  }, []);
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  if (name == "") {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div className="bg-lightgrey min-h-screen flex justify-center items-center flex-row">
      <div className="container mx-auto max-w-sm py-10">
        <div className="rounded-md shadow-lg py-4 px-4 bg-white">
          <p className="text-black font-bold text-3xl">{room}</p>
          <p>{name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="ml-2 container mx-auto max-w-sm py-10">
        <div className="rounded-md shadow-lg py-4 px-4 bg-white">
          <p className="text-black font-bold text-3xl">{room}</p>
          <p>{name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const data = await query;
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } };
}
```

and this is the respond i got in my terminal

[image: reponseimg]

the tutorial is using reactjs, but i'm `using nextjs`, is it different? i'm sorry if i have broken english, hope you guys understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i fixed it, i think its because i have different version of my socket.io and socket.io-client.